# Ag-Grid - Tooltips (Bootstrap) when cell is rendered

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, tooltip, ag-grid

I am looking to trigger a specific Javascript on a cell as soon as it is rendered (Bootstrap tooltip to be specific). The table has >30 columns and >500 rows. I auto size the columns.

I trigger the tooltip init onVirtualColumnsChanged and onViewportChanged as well as onGridReady (just to be sure ^^'). But autosize does not seem to trigger any of these. The columns which come into view after autosize do not have tooltips accordingly. Even if I trigger tooltips at the end of autosizing.

Does anybody have any idea what would be the best to have Bootstrap tooltips inited on potentially each cell as soon as it is rendered?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: See how to create [mcve]. The idea is you describe what you want to do, show what you tried, and tell us what results you get. reproduce your issue on plunk or stackblitz so that others can help you easily.